# How to avoid soql query limit?

Tags: apex, soql

i have some trouble with my Apex Class. I am hiting the governor limit and i have problems imporving my code. Can someone help me?

```
public class WarengruppenZuordnung {
/********************* Properties used by getRootNodeOfUserTree function - starts **********************/
// map to hold roles with Id as the key
private static Map <Id, Warengruppen_Struktur__c> warengruppeMap;

// map to hold child roles with parentRoleId as the key
private static Map <Id, List<Warengruppen_Struktur__c>> parentWarengruppeMap;

// List holds all subordinates
private static List<Warengruppen_Struktur__c> allProducts {get; set;}

// Global JSON generator
private static JSONGenerator gen {get; set;}
public static String folderId{get;set;}
public static String folderName{get;set;}
public static String endpointId{get;set;}
/********************* Properties used by getRootNodeOfUserTree function - ends **********************/


/********************* Properties used by getSObjectTypeById function - starts ********************* */
// map to hold global describe data
private static Map<String,Schema.SObjectType> gd;

// map to store objects and their prefixes
private static Map<String, String> keyPrefixMap;

// to hold set of all sObject prefixes
private static Set<String> keyPrefixSet;
/********************* Properties used by getSObjectTypeById function - ends **********************/

public static String redirUrl{get;set;}
public String contactId {get;set;}

/* // initialize helper data */ 
static {
    // initialize helper data for getSObjectTypeById function
    Map<String, String> UrlParameterMap = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters();
    //redirUrl = getRedirUrl();
    gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
    init1();
    gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
    // initialize helper data for getRootNodeOfUserTree function
    init2();
}

/* // init1 starts <to initialise helper data> */
private static void init1() {
    // get all objects from the org
    gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
    // to store objects and their prefixes
    keyPrefixMap = new Map<String, String>{};

        //get the object prefix in IDs
        keyPrefixSet = gd.keySet();

    // fill up the prefixes map
    for(String sObj : keyPrefixSet) {
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r =  gd.get(sObj).getDescribe();
        String tempName = r.getName();
        String tempPrefix = r.getKeyPrefix();
        keyPrefixMap.put(tempPrefix, tempName);
    }
}
/* // init1 ends */

/* // init2 starts <to initialise helper data> */
private static void init2() {

    // Create a blank list
    allProducts = new List<Warengruppen_Struktur__c>();

    for(AggregateResult wsc : [SELECT Name, RecordTypeId, RecordType.DeveloperName FROM Warengruppen_Struktur__c GROUP BY RecordTypeId, RecordType.DeveloperName, Name ORDER BY Name]) {
        if(String.valueOf(wsc.get('DeveloperName')).contains('Ordner')){
            folderId = String.valueOf(wsc.get('RecordTypeId'));
            folderName = String.valueOf(wsc.get('Name'));
        }
        if(String.valueOf(wsc.get('DeveloperName')).contains('Endpunkt')){
            endpointId = String.valueOf(wsc.get('RecordTypeId'));

        }
    }

    warengruppeMap = new Map<Id, Warengruppen_Struktur__c>([select Id, Name, Parent_Warengruppe__c, RecordTypeId from Warengruppen_Struktur__c order by Name]);
    // populate parent role - child roles map
    parentWarengruppeMap = new Map <Id, List<Warengruppen_Struktur__c>>();        
    for (Warengruppen_Struktur__c r : warengruppeMap.values()) {
        List<Warengruppen_Struktur__c> tempList;
        if (!parentWarengruppeMap.containsKey(r.Parent_Warengruppe__c)){
            tempList = new List<Warengruppen_Struktur__c>();
            tempList.Add(r);
            parentWarengruppeMap.put(r.Parent_Warengruppe__c, tempList);
        }
        else {
            tempList = (List<Warengruppen_Struktur__c>)parentWarengruppeMap.get(r.Parent_Warengruppe__c);
            tempList.add(r);
            parentWarengruppeMap.put(r.Parent_Warengruppe__c, tempList);
        }
    }
} 
/* // init2 ends */

/* // public method to get the starting node of the RoleTree along with user list */
public static RoleNodeWrapper getRootNodeOfUserTree (Id userOrRoleId) {
    return createNode(userOrRoleId);
}

/* // createNode starts */
private static RoleNodeWrapper createNode(Id objId) {
    RoleNodeWrapper n = new RoleNodeWrapper();
    Id roleId;
    if (isRole(objId)) {
        roleId = objId;
        if (!(warengruppeMap.get(objId).Parent_Warengruppe__c == null)) {
            List<Warengruppen_Struktur__c> tempFolderList = new List<Warengruppen_Struktur__c>();
            Warengruppen_Struktur__c tempFolder = [Select Id, Name, Parent_Warengruppe__c, RecordTypeId, RecordType.DeveloperName from Warengruppen_Struktur__c where Id =: objId ORDER BY Name];
            tempFolderList.add(tempFolder);
            if(tempFolderList.size()== 1){
                if(tempFolderList[0].RecordType.DeveloperName.contains('Ordner')){
                    n.hasFolders = false;
                    n.myFolders = tempFolderList;
                    n.isLeafNode = false;
                    allProducts.addAll(n.myFolders);
                }
                else{
                    n.hasFolders = false;
                    n.myFolders = tempFolderList;
                    n.isLeafNode = true;
                    allProducts.addAll(n.myFolders);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        List<Warengruppen_Struktur__c> tempFolderList = new List<Warengruppen_Struktur__c>();
        Warengruppen_Struktur__c tempFolder = [Select Id, Name, Parent_Warengruppe__c, RecordTypeId from Warengruppen_Struktur__c where Id =: objId ORDER BY Name];
        tempFolderList.add(tempFolder);
        n.myFolders = tempFolderList;
        roleId = tempFolder.Parent_Warengruppe__c;
    }
    n.myRoleId = roleId;
    n.myRoleName = warengruppeMap.get(roleId).Name;
    n.myParentRoleId = warengruppeMap.get(roleId).Parent_Warengruppe__c;
    n.RecordTypeId = warengruppeMap.get(roleId).RecordTypeId;
    if (parentWarengruppeMap.containsKey(roleId)){
        n.hasChildren = true;
        n.isLeafNode = false;
        List<RoleNodeWrapper> lst = new List<RoleNodeWrapper>();
        for (Warengruppen_Struktur__c r : parentWarengruppeMap.get(roleId)) {
            lst.add(createNode(r.Id));
        }           
        n.myChildNodes = lst;
    }
    else {
        n.isLeafNode = true;
        n.hasChildren = false;

    }
    return n;
}

public static List<Warengruppen_Struktur__c> getAllProducts(Id warengruppeId){
    createNode(warengruppeId);
    return allProducts;
}

public static String getTreeJSON(Id userOrRoleId) {
    gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
    RoleNodeWrapper node = createNode(userOrRoleId);
    gen.writeStartArray();
    convertNodeToJSON(node);
    gen.writeEndArray();
    return gen.getAsString();
}

public static String getTreeJSON() {
    gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
    List<Warengruppen_Struktur__c> wRoots = [Select Id, Name, RecordTypeId From Warengruppen_Struktur__c Where Parent_Warengruppe__c = '' ORDER BY Name];
    gen.writeStartArray();
    for(Warengruppen_Struktur__c ws : wRoots){
        RoleNodeWrapper node = createNode(ws.Id);
        convertNodeToJSON(node);
    }
    gen.writeEndArray();
    return gen.getAsString();
}

private static void convertNodeToJSON(RoleNodeWrapper objRNW){
    gen.writeStartObject();
    gen.writeStringField('title', objRNW.myRoleName);
    gen.writeStringField('key', objRNW.myRoleId);
    gen.writeStringField('RecordTypeID', String.valueOf(objRNW.RecordTypeId));
    gen.writeBooleanField('unselectable', false);
    gen.writeBooleanField('expand', true);
    gen.writeBooleanField('isFolder', true);
    if (objRNW.hasFolders || objRNW.hasChildren)
    {
        gen.writeFieldName('children');
        gen.writeStartArray();
        if (objRNW.hasFolders)
        {
            for (Warengruppen_Struktur__c u : objRNW.myFolders)
            {
                gen.writeStartObject();
                gen.writeStringField('title', u.Name);
                gen.writeStringField('key', u.Id);
                gen.writeStringField('RecordTypeID', String.valueOf(objRNW.RecordTypeId));
                gen.writeBooleanField('isFolder', false);
                gen.WriteEndObject();
            }
        }
        if (objRNW.hasChildren)
        {

            for (RoleNodeWrapper r : objRNW.myChildNodes)

            {
                convertNodeToJSON(r);

            }
        }
        gen.writeEndArray();
    }
    gen.writeEndObject();
}

/* // general utility function to get the SObjectType of the Id passed as the argument, to be used in conjunction with */ 
public static String getSObjectTypeById(Id objectId) {
    String tPrefix = objectId;
    tPrefix = tPrefix.subString(0,3);
    String objectType = keyPrefixMap.get(tPrefix);
    return objectType;
}
/* // utility function getSObjectTypeById ends */

/* // check the object type of objId using the utility function getSObjectTypeById and return 'true' if it's of Role type */
public static Boolean isRole (Id objId) {
    if (getSObjectTypeById(objId) == String.valueOf(Warengruppen_Struktur__c.sObjectType)) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (getSObjectTypeById(objId) != String.valueOf(Warengruppen_Struktur__c.sObjectType)) {
        return false;
    } 
    return false;
}
/* // isRole ends */

public class RoleNodeWrapper {

    // Role info properties - begin
    public String myRoleName {get; set;}

    public Id myRoleId {get; set;}
    public Id RecordTypeId {get; set;}
    public String myParentRoleId {get; set;}
    // Role info properties - end


    // Node children identifier properties - begin
    public Boolean hasChildren {get; set;}

    public Boolean isLeafNode {get; set;}

    public Boolean hasFolders {get; set;}
    // Node children identifier properties - end


    // Node children properties - begin
    public List<Warengruppen_Struktur__c> myFolders {get; set;}

    public List<RoleNodeWrapper> myChildNodes {get; set;}
    // Node children properties - end   

    public RoleNodeWrapper(){
        hasFolders = false;
        hasChildren = false;
    }
}

public static String getRedirUrl(){
    Map<String, String> UrlParameterMap = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters();
    redirUrl = UrlParameterMap.values()[1];
    return redirUrl;        
}

public String getContactId()
{
    return Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');

}

}
```

The log says the error occurs in this line:

```
Warengruppen_Struktur__c tempFolder = [Select Id, Name, Parent_Warengruppe__c, RecordTypeId, RecordType.DeveloperName from Warengruppen_Struktur__c where Id =: objId ORDER BY Name];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have queries in the loops, even though you don't immediately see them and code review tools won't find them either.
The query that gives problem is in `createNode()` method, and you call this method from the loops at least on 2 places:

```
for(Warengruppen_Struktur__c ws : wRoots){
    RoleNodeWrapper node = createNode(ws.Id);
    convertNodeToJSON(node);
}
```

and

```
for (Warengruppen_Struktur__c r : parentWarengruppeMap.get(roleId)) {
    lst.add(createNode(r.Id));
}
```

Also, depending on the implementation, check that methods `getRootNodeOfUserTree()` and `getAllProducts()` are not being called within a loop, since they also call the same method `createNode()`

Comment: Can i use my existing map to perform all sorting and JSON generation? 
   warengruppeMap = new Map<Id, Warengruppen_Struktur__c>([select Id, Name, Parent_Warengruppe__c, RecordTypeId from Warengruppen_Struktur__c order by Name]);